# Windows 8.1 can't access SambaDroid server

Tags: cyanogenmod, windows, htc-one, file-sharing

I'm trying to set up and smb server using SambaDroid on my HTC One (M7) running Cyanogenmod 12.1 to sync certain folder on my Windows 8.1 laptop. Once the service starts running on my phone, I can see the SambaDroid appear in my networks on my laptop.

If I click it, I see the sdcard folder. However, if I try to open the sdcard folder, a window pops up that says `Windows cannot access \\SambaDroid\sdcard`. If I try to map the network to a drive I get the same error. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Additional details:

- My wifi network is on the wifi whitelist.
- File sharing is enabled for the wifi network on my laptop.
- Both SambaDroid and laptop are connected to the same wifi network.
- Under 'Manage Shares' in the app, the sdcard and all its contented show up and have RW access.
- In win8.1 in Network and Sharing Center I have allowed file sharing for 40 and 56 bit encryptions (the only other option is allow only 128bit)

*Edit: I've seen on some threads that I need to change the local security policy, but this feature of Admin Tools is only available on the pro version of Win 8.1*

Comment: This is probably an issue with Windows rather than Android. Please add additional details to clarify where the issue might actually lie so we can address it properly.

Comment: what sort of details do you need? I'm a newb to the whole file sharing server thing.

Comment: For example, does your laptop work correctly with a dedicated (hardware-based) NAS Server (Samba host)? Have you correctly configured the SambaDroid app? Can SambaDroid access the SD card normally? etc.

Comment: I don't have a dedicated server to check this. Is there another way I can see what kind of problem the laptop has connecting to a Samba host? I have updated the post a little more. I honestly just don't know much about connecting to a server, but I don't mind reading up on something relevant if you can link any information that might help.

Comment: To be honest, I've never used an NAS, so I can't help you enough. I suggested some general troubleshooting steps. +1ed your question as I feel it should get a bit more attention, but I suspect this is the wrong site for the job. You could try SuperUser, but do ask for a migration by flagging it for a moderator, don't cross-post

Comment: If you have another device to cross-check (e.g. an Android device with a Samba client, or a Linux machine), that might help narrowing down the issue – and e.g. see on which end the culprit sits. If no other client can connect either, it might be the server; if others can connect fine, it's rather Win8 as client.